# Set Font Size in TWebBrowser Selection

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I have a email client which allows the user to change font, font size, bold, italics etc.

The issue l am having is when l try to change the font size of the selection either up or down i get a **"EVariantTypeCastError" with a message of "Could not convert variant of type Null into type OleStr".** This exception gets thrown on     TextRange.queryCommandValue('FONTSIZE').

```
procedure TForm1.act_FontIncreaseExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
    Selection: IHTMLSelectionObject;
    HtmlPage: IHTMLDocument2;
    TextRange: IHTMLTxtRange;
    Parent: IHTMLElement2;
    s: string;
    i, mode: Integer;
begin

    HtmlPage := self.HtmlEditor.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
    Selection := HtmlPage.Selection;

    TextRange := Selection.createRange as IHTMLTxtRange;
    if (TextRange <> nil) then
    begin
        s := TextRange.queryCommandValue('FONTSIZE');
        val(s, i, mode);
        if mode = 0 then
            HtmlPage.execCommand('FONTSIZE', False, inttostr(i + 1))
    end;
end;
```

Is this the correct approach to increase the size of the font for the selection?

**Edit 1:**

Sample HTML:

```
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>
    <SPAN style='FONT-SIZE: 7pt;'>
        Test Text
    </SPAN>
</P>
</BODY></HTML>
```

It looks like the issue lies with the FONT-SIZE Style. When this is taken out then no exception is thrown. My end goal is to be able to copy and paste from outlook and this is a stripped down example of that. When l use other styles such as color:red then no exceptions are thrown. So it looks like its just FONT-SIZE that is has the issue with.

**Edit 2**

Exception Stack Trace

[image: Exception Stack Trace]

Comment: The argement for Query/Exec is Olevariant. FontSize wont always return an integer, in your case it seems to return nothing (null). However I can't reproduce your error, can you edit the question and include a piece of html that reproduces the error?

Comment: Thanks for you help, i'll update the question with a sample

Comment: `FONTSIZE` command refers to `FONT` tag surrounding the text range: e.g. `<FONT size=1>Test Text</FONT>`. In your HTML example you need  to handle the style attribute/element.

Comment: @kobik thanks for you help. When l switch the span to a font and change the attribute to size like you mentioned then l no longer get the exception. This HTML is pasted straight from a outlook signature. Is there a reason why outlook signatures would put FONT-SIZE in a span? I get the same error when copying from Word as well

Comment: FONT tag is not supported in html5. Outlook/Word uses CSS which is the preferred way in modern HTML.

Comment: @kobik Thanks, that makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out, in some cases the query will return `NULL` and then the `Val()` command will fail.

The solution is simple, assume standard font size when you get null:

```
procedure TForm1.FontIncreaseExecute;

var
    Selection: IHTMLSelectionObject;
    HtmlPage: IHTMLDocument2;
    TextRange: IHTMLTxtRange;
    s: OleVariant;
    i, mode: Integer;

 begin  
  HtmlPage := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  Selection := HtmlPage.Selection;
  TextRange := Selection.createRange as IHTMLTxtRange;
  if (TextRange <> nil) then
   begin
    s := TextRange.queryCommandValue('FONTSIZE');
    if VarisNull(s) then
     s := 0; // fall back to standard font size
    Val(s, i, mode);
    if mode = 0 then
    HtmlPage.execCommand('FONTSIZE', False, inttostr(i + 1))
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. queryCommandValue throws the exception so VarisNull won't help in this case. I'd have to use a try except statement. Any idea as to why it is null in this case?

Comment: @MattLaza: Then you are not using the code you posted here. Debug your application and provide a stack trace...

Comment: I am definitely using the code l have provided. I have also attached a screenshot of the stack trace. You can see the exception is being thrown in System.Variants

Comment: @MattLaza, note that whosrdaddy uses `s: OleVariant` while you use `s: string`. Have you tried his code with `VarisNull` check? in any case you may be able to handle the exception but `queryCommandValue` wont ever give you the font size you are looking for as I explained in my comments.

Comment: @Kobik that explains indeed why he has the exception on the query due to implicit conversion from null variant to string.

Comment: @MattLaza: did you even bother to try out my answer?

Comment: @whosrdaddy i missing the part where where you changed s from a string to OLEVariant. My Apologies

Answer (score 3):

> Is this the correct approach to increase the size of the font for the
>   selection?

`.queryCommandValue('FONTSIZE')` refers to the [`FONT`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_font.asp) tag surrounding the text range (font sizes 1-7): e.g.

```
<FONT size=1>Test Text</FONT>
```

In your HTML example there is no `FONT` tag. You need to handle the `FONT-SIZE` **Style** attribute (CSS) of the surrounding `SPAN`.

e.g. (no error checking to simplify the example):

```
if (TextRange <> nil) then
begin
  ...
  ShowMessage(TextRange.parentElement.style.fontSize);
end;
```

This will show `7pt`.
Your specific exception cause is explained by @whosrdaddy [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40107735/937125) (`queryCommandValue` returns null for the reason I explained)